# Finite precision - how to get rid of "near zeros"

Tags: matrix, machine-precision, number-representation

I am performing a finite-precision operation on a matrix `A` which I know precisely; call the result `B`. The operation is taking the square root by `B = MatrixPower[A,1/2]`, but it's not quite relevant. The point is that the form of `A` is such that the output will contain a lot of entries equal to `0`, simply because `A` has a lot of invariant subspaces spanned by the standard base vectors.

I would like to see resulting matrix is like: in the first approximation it interests me how many non-zero entries it has and where. The problem is, the entries of `B` which are supposed to be `0` come out as small reals of the type $1.234...\times 10^{-10}$. I've tried applying `N` to `B` with some modest requirement on precision, but this does not seem to help. Ideally, I would like to set all entries of `B` which are approximately `0` to precisely `0`. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. It just occurred to me that I can take a function `f` that maps small numbers to `0`, and is identity otherwise, and apply it to `B` element-wise. But there should be a more elegant solution, it seems to me.

Comment: Take a look at `Chop`.

Comment: @Kuba: Precisely what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18485#18485).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you will find [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html?q=Chop&lang=en) useful.

Comment: Chop is just what I was looking for. Thank you!